# Intel fortran optimisation prevent Tempoary Array Elimination (FTAE)

Tags: optimization, fortran, intel-fortran

I have a piece of Fortran code from a large package as, (the subroutine is stripped to only show relevant part)

```
    subroutine subp(arr,n)
         ! This subroutine is part of a parent module. `vol` is a real(kind=8) number, `nsj` is integer both are inherited from a top-level module
        complex(kind=8), intent(inout) :: arr(nsj) ! arr is non zero
        integer, intent(inout) :: n
        complex(kind=8), dimension(nsj) :: f0,f1,f2

        !!!! If I do this f1 becomes 0 ------------------------------
        f1 = arr*sqrt(vol)  
        f2=f1   
        f0=0
        !-----------------------------------------------------------


        !!!! If I do this, instead of the above, f2 becomes 0-------
        f2 = arr*sqrt(vol) 
        f1=f2   
        f0=0
        !-----------------------------------------------------------

        !!! If I do this all things stays correct------------------
        f2 = arr*sqrt(vol) 
        f1 = arr*sqrt(vol)    
        f0=0
        !----------------------------------------------------------

        do i=1,n
            print *, 'f1', sum(f1)
            print *, 'f2', sum(f2)
            call test(f2)

            f2=f2-d(i)*f1-f0*e(i)
            f0=f1
            f1= f2
            ! store the arrays f1, f2
        end do

        ! caluculation on `arr` with stored f1,f2

    end
```

`array`, `f1`, `f2` are all large complex double precision 1D array. This code works as intended with `-O3` but the value of `f2` (or `f1` depending of code) becomes `0` when compiled with `-O3 -ipo`. A quick check with `-qopt-report` shows something like this happening at that line

```
remark #25050: 
Tempoary Array Elimination (FTAE) Report: 
ftae for the loop at line *****
```

Seems like `ifort` considers `f1` (for first case) as intermediate temporary array and eliminates it. It doesn't see the array `f1` is used ahead in the calculation.
What is going wrong here and how do I prevent this here and make sure this doesn't happen in future.
I'm using `ifort (IFORT) 2021.3.0 20210609`

Comment: We would really need more code. And best the code of the compiler itself. I would rather contact Intel at the official venue. They will need more code as well.

Comment: What is `vol`? Please make an actual [mcve].

Comment: If the procedure can be optimized to remove the need to use a large temporary array, why do you think something has gone wrong and that that's something you need to fix? As you've asked for IPO the compiler probably knows about `test`: for humans to comment they'd also need to see that subroutine.

Comment: How are you testing the value of `f2`: it's totally unreferenced before the entry of `test` the first time (where it may be that it's not referenced).

Comment: Okay, updated few details.

Comment: It should be really simple to take the subroutine and put it into a short program that is verifiable and testable. Yes, we can also do that, but it is completely essential that we know that this actually fails for you. Therefore, really, please make an actual [mcve]. Just try to call this subroutine and see. Then we can try to identify any problem.

Comment: Giving a complete example is particularly important given the `-ipo` flag. Turning on inter-procedural optimisation for a single procedure seems unlikely to break things.

Comment: The actual/complete suite of code/ package is owned by someone else, and I can not post that publically. I will try to reproduce the problem, writing a similar part of the code. If I am able to reproduce the problem, I will certainly update here.